# oDeskTeam crashes uder OpenSUSE 11.3

Tags: linux, opensuse, suse, opensuse-11.3

Does anybody know a workaround for the problem? 
I tried all rpms and statically linked versions, some are just not installable anymore and some crash after few seconds of logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

o.k. after some talks with oDesk support team they provided me a fixed rpm for the 11.3 :)